# Question about notation of subgroups of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, permutations

sorry if this is a basic question, but I was reading about the permutation group $S_3$, and I read that it has three subgroups: $\langle y\rangle$, $\langle xy\rangle$, $\langle x^2y\rangle$ of order 2 and $\langle x\rangle$ of order 3.

Can someone mention which subgroups these are, and how to determine their order? are any of these groups normal?

Comment: it seems that $y=(12), x=(123)$. Are you familiar with this notation?

Comment: I'm familiar with (12) and (123)

Comment: Suggestion (not a hint for this particular question). I recommend that you write down all $6$ elements of $S_3$ in cycle notation (which you seem to know how to do) and then do lots of multiplications. For this question: find out what subgroup each of the six elements generates.Then test each for normality, using the definition.